# How to Increase the timeout for a get request in kibana devconsole

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-7

i am using elk 7.1.1 with x-pack installed.

I am trying to perform a get command in kibana dev console to get the list of all snapshots

```
GET _cat/snapshots/<myrepositoryname>/
```

output

```
{
  "statusCode": 504,
  "error": "Gateway Time-out",
  "message": "Client request timeout"
}
```

and i also tried

```
 GET _cat/snapshots/<myrepositoryname>/?waitforcompletion=true
```

But its not working.Please help me solve it.

Comment: hey Vamsi, was my answer of any help?

Answer (score 3):

Old Questions but maybe its helps others. To increase timout you can set the timout parameter as query parameter like:

```
POST my_index/_search?timeout=9000s
```

The s is for seconds. You can use other time shortcuts as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to set a query-specific timeout by using the Elasticsearch Query DSL. Also, that option doesn't seem dynamically updateable at all (I got a `illegal_argument_exception` when I tried to update it by using the `_cluster/settings` API).

Then, the only way I know to increase the period to wait for a response is by increasing the value of the `timeout` setting in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file.

However, I would suggest you (1) to check whether the resources (RAM, CPU) you assigned to your cluster are sufficient, and (2) to use some naming/lifecycle conventions for your snapshots, so that to add a more fine-grained way to filter them other than just by grouping snapshots by a repository name (e.g., naming convention `<year>-<month>-<day_time>-snapshot`, then you could run narrow down your search e.g., `GET _cat/snapshots/<myrepositoryname>/2020-January-*`).

PS. The `wait_for_completion` query parameter is only blocking the request until a response from the server is received, but has nothing to do with the timeout.